# Removing quarkus.package.type=legacy-jar leads to not finding DataTypeFactoryImpl

Tags: java, quarkus

We removed the `legacy-jar` option from the `application.properties`. However, when running the code in our openshift cluster I get the following class not found exception:

```
14:42:22 WARN  [nl.bro.mic.com.rs.pro.DefaultExceptionProvider] (executor-thread-12) javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl not found: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl not found
    at nl.bro.microservices.rba.be.mapping.models.ModelXmlMapperImpl.<init>(ModelXmlMapperImpl.java:42
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.RunnerClassLoader.loadClass(RunnerClassLoader.java:115)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.RunnerClassLoader.loadClass(RunnerClassLoader.java:65)
    at javax.xml.datatype.FactoryFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.datatype.FactoryFinder.find(Unknown Source)
    ... 70 more
```

The docker file takes care on copying our jars to the target location:

```
COPY --chown=185 target/quarkus-app/lib/ /deployments/lib/
COPY --chown=185 target/quarkus-app/*.jar /deployments/
COPY --chown=185 target/quarkus-app/app/ /deployments/app/
COPY --chown=185 target/quarkus-app/quarkus/ /deployments/quarkus/
```

This is not happening in dev mode (locally). I tried a lot of things. Most prominent is adding the dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-jaxb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

version Quarkus: 2.16.6.Final, Java 11 (openjdk)

What are we missing? I can see its looking for the class without the `com.sun` package prefix

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. I found it. Somehow classloading order has changed. I now included:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>${xerces.xercesimpl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

And a SPI definition:

```
javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory
```

with content

```
org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl
```

forcing using this factory always (and not the java internal one).

This fixed it.